# RIA Services exposing nested objects

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I am having an issue exposing my nested object VIA WCF RIA Service.

Example of business objects (not tied to DB)

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }

}
```

The user object will come to my client object, however the product does not. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it in the query like this:

```
var MyUsers = DataContext.Users.Include("Product").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the [Include] tag in User metadata? It will identify it as information that should be sent over the network.

Comment: Yes I added Include but to do so you are required to use the [Association] attribute and in this case there really isn't a mapping between person and product. Can I just fake the relationship?

Answer (score 0):

If there isnt a mapping, use a LINQ query: some pseudocode

var user= from u in User
          join Product on User.Key = Product.Key
          select u;

Answer (score 0):

```
[Include]
public Product Product { get; set; }
```